# Stackblitz, Angular Including JSON file not working

Tags: json, angular, stackblitz

I'm using Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/bible-talk

I'm using Angular 10.

I'm trying to import data from a JSON file.

I found an example on how to do this on Stackblitz:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/json-import-example?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

You're supposed to add these to compiler options to `tsconfig.json`:

```
"resolveJsonModule": true,
"esModuleInterop": true,
"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
```

I've done that: https://github.com/JaredMathis/bible-talk/commit/449f6269b85bb53eb5aa245bd709075db4307163

I'm still getting this error:

```
Error in src/app/app.component.ts (2:18)
Cannot find module '../assets/kjv/John.json' or its corresponding type declarations.
```

I made a brand-new Stackblitz. It works there. https://stackblitz.com/edit/json-import-not-working?file=tsconfig.json

Answer (score 1):

Stackblitz does not support static assets at the moment.
See: https://github.com/stackblitz/core/issues/72

Workaround: You have to host your static assets somewhere else and link them in your code appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

Your I think import in your github version is wrong, it starts with `./` where as your working stackblitz does not.

```
import data from './../assets/John.json';
```

Try removing the first `./`

Comment: Sorry to hear... Just an FYI we tried to do something like this at work the other day and ended up not getting it working.  We gave up and went back to using http requests to get the JSON data as it just wasn't worth the effort.  Was there a reason you can't request the data via an http request?