React i18next Typescript error using t('key') always need to specify namespace
After following exactly the document provided here to type correctly my translation key, I hope to use t('key') with a fully typed on my translation function. But on my simple StackBlitz example, I always need to prefix my key with namespace, even if I import it correctly in useTranslation('ns1').
const TranslationItem = () => {
  const { t } = useTranslation('ns1');

  return (
    <div>
      <div>Type Error : {t('title')}</div>
      <div>No Type Error : {t('ns1:title')}</div>
    </div>
  );
};

When I specify a namespace, I should use the simple key without prefixing with ns1:
const TranslationItem = () => {
  const { t } = useTranslation('ns1');

  return (
    <div>
      <div>Works well : {t('title')}</div>
    </div>
  );
};


your code works fine in Visual Studio code but it does give typescript error in StackBlitz
Type instantiation is excessively deep and possibly infinite.

the reason is that Stackblitz does not support static assets at the moment.
so your file can not read JSON.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/65291298/23400426
one workaround is to make your JSON file in .ts extension and refresh the browser, that should fix the problem.
const ns1 = {
title: 'Welcome to react using react-i18next fully type-safe',
description: {
  part1: 'This is a simple example.',
  part2: '',
},
  title2: 'tete',
};

export default ns1;

